# Github Copilot won't retrieve suggestions on Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, github-copilot

Recently installed the latest copilot version (currently 1.1.28.1744) and the latest pycharm (currently 2022.2) and I can't get copilot to work on it.

The login and permission part goes through without any problems.

Once installed it is always "retrieving suggestions" forever, after I click refresh. But it never retrieves any.

I found a discussion on github community that suggested copying the software logs to facilitate any help, you can find the logs which I frankly do not understand on [this discussion link](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/28510).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue with DataSpell. I hope they fix the integration.

Comment: They released an update that included proxy integration but it didn't change anything for me...

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you're behind a proxy. If that's the case, you can try configuring your proxy info in IntelliJ following [this documentation](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/29127).

Comment: Thanks a lot. A few like that is the problem, because I can't complete the curl in that documentation. The problem is that even with proxy in the curl i still can't complete... still investigating

Answer (score 0):

I am using macbook pro m1 2021. I was facing the same problem with the new version of pycharm 2022.3 . After long researches I found out that you have to install an older version. I have installed the 2022.1.4 version of pycharm and copilot works fine!
I hope this can help.